# $\mathbb{Z}_p[\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^n})]$-modules

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime. Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the $p$-adic integers.

I'm intersted in $\mathbb{Z}_p[\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^n})]$-modules of low rank over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (rank $2$ is already very interesting).

Is there a characterization of such modules? Where can I find examples? What are good books or other resources to learn about them?

I'm familiar with complex representations of finite groups, with the $p$-adic numbers, and somewhat familiar with group cohomology (if that's at all relevant).

Comment: Such a module would give a complex representation of low rank. Most PGL2 do not have such a representation other than 1-dimensional. For the specific rank of 2, one only has PGL(2,2)=S3 and PGL(2,3)=S4, which have integral reps with the same character (not just complex, not just p-adic integer, but actually Z).

Comment: To clarify, are you just interested in modules that are free over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Yes, I am only looking for modules that are free over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I don't know why such modules would give complex reps, but assuming your argument is correct - I need to rethink about my question.

Comment: @Olnek: Tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$, then take coefficients in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then consider that extension as living in $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  It's sort of a standard fact about characteristic 0 representations, generally called character theory. It is explained explicitly in Isaacs's *Character Theory of Finite Groups* for sure, and I think in most books on that topic.

Comment: (If you didn't require the modules to be torsion-free over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then such modules do exist, but they are really just over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ (where $k$ is bounded above, I believe, but I'm not exactly sure by what) which is mostly just asking about over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I think you need $n=1$ to get low rank there.)

Comment: For PSL rather than PGL, I think Holt–Plesken's *Perfect Groups* has some nice results and tables, but I don't have a copy handy. Again the p,n that occur in low ranks (up to rank 10 or so in the book, I think?) are pretty limited.